# Local Maxima of List in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

This is a simple coding exercise: find all the *local maxima* in given list. A *local maximum* is an item, which is greater than both the items immediately before and after it.

```
localMaxima of [2,9,5,6,1] is [9,6]
localMaxima of [2,3,4,1,5] == [4]
localMaxima of [1,2,3,4,5] == []
```

I wrote the this function as follows:

```
def localMaxima(l: List[Int]) = 
  (l, l.tail, l.tail.tail).zipped.toList
    .filter(t => t._2 > t._1 && t._2 > t._3)
    .map(_._2)
```

How would you write *local maxima* ?

Comment: `localMaxima of [1]`?

Comment: localMaxima of [1] is []. Unfortunately, my function does not handle this case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
scala> val l = List(2,9,5,6,1)
l: List[Int] = List(2, 9, 5, 6, 1)

scala> l.sliding(3).collect{ case a::b::c::Nil if a<b && b>c => b }.toList
res2: List[Int] = List(9, 6)

scala> val l = List(2,3,4,1,5)
l: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4, 1, 5)

scala> l.sliding(3).collect{ case a::b::c::Nil if a<b && b>c => b }.toList
res3: List[Int] = List(4)

scala> val l = List(1,2,3,4,5)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> l.sliding(3).collect{ case a::b::c::Nil if a<b && b>c => b }.toList
res4: List[Int] = List()
```

Comment: I would probably replace `a::b::c::Nil` with `List(a, b, c)`.

Answer (score 9):

I would use sliding function:

```
def localMaxima(list : List[Int]) = list.sliding(3).foldLeft(List[Int]()){
    case (seed, Seq(a, b,c)) => if(b > a && b > c) b:: seed else seed
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using a for comprehension on

```
val a = List(2,9,5,6,1)
```

like this,

```
for ( (v,w,u) <- (a,a.drop(1),a.drop(2)).zipped if v < w && w > u ) yield w
```

**Update**

Using `filter` like this,

```
(1 to a.size-2).filter(i => a(i-1) < a(i) && a(i) > a(i+1) ).map(a(_)).toList
```